# Go image draw square

Tags: image, go

I currently want to set pixel images on a loop

```
func ParseMap(path string) {
    ...
    for _, h := range serverMap.Houses {
        houseData := Houses.GetHouse(h.ID)
        houseImage := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(int(houseData.EntryX)-32, int(houseData.EntryY)-32, int(houseData.EntryX)+32, int(houseData.EntryY)+32))
        draw.Draw(houseImage, houseImage.Bounds(), &image.Uniform{
            backgroundColor,
        }, image.ZP, draw.Src)
        for _, tile := range h.Tiles {
            pos := tile.Position()
            if pos.Z != uint8(houseData.EntryZ) {
                continue
            }
            drawSquare(houseImage, tileColor, 12, int(pos.X), int(pos.Y))
        imgFile, _ := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%v/%v/%v.png", pigo.Config.String("template"), "public/houses", houseData.Name))
        png.Encode(imgFile, houseImage)
        imgFile.Close()
    }
    ...
}
```

I loop on a slice of Tiles that contains X, Y, Z fields but since 1 pixel looks very small I want to be each pixel 6 pixel square with the given function

```
func drawSquare(img *image.RGBA, c color.Color, size int, x, y int) {
    patch := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, size, size))
    draw.Draw(patch, patch.Bounds(), &image.Uniform{
        c,
    }, image.ZP, draw.Src)
    draw.Draw(img, image.Rect(x, y, x+size, y+size), patch, image.ZP, draw.Src)
}
```

However there is a problem with this function. If I want to paint one pixel this is how it will look

[image]

The red borders means how big the square will be  BUT if I go to the next pixel the size will be overwritten

[image]

Instead of beeing what I am looking for

[image]

I hope it is clear enough what I want to achieve but I dont really know what type of algorithm I should use (if I even need one) or its just pure logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pondering it a bit, I think I know the issue. It is with this line:

```
draw.Draw(img, image.Rect(x, y, x+size, y+size), patch, image.ZP, draw.Src)
```

You add the size only to make each rectangle large, but you do not multiply it with the position.

```
draw.Draw(img, image.Rect(x*size, y*size, x+size, y+size), patch, image.ZP, draw.Src)
```

You might need to tweek this depending on your grid.